# Erro imap roundcube

Tags: php, gmail, roundcube

```
IMAP Error: OpenSSL not available in C:\wamp\www\roundcubemail-1.0.3\program\lib\Roundcube\rcube_imap.php on line 129 (POST /roundcubemail-1.0.3/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)

IMAP Error: Login failed for leandrogabrielbustamante@gmail.com from 127.0.0.1. Empty startup greeting (imap.gmail.com:993) in C:\wamp\www\roundcubemail-1.0.3\program\lib\Roundcube\rcube_imap.php on line 184 (POST /roundcubemail-1.0.3/?_task=login?_task=login&_action=login)
```

I try to login from roundcube with gmail account but I see this error in logs / errors. Please if someone would help me.

Comment: Have you installed the 'php*-common' package ?
I've always had it by default and don't remember doing anything manually.

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your `php.ini` (usually somewhere around /etc/php/) the `extension=openssl.so` is in use.